# Can anybody explain how exactly Filter and IndexOf methods work together in a function?

Tags: javascript

I have the following function, which pretty much does what it supposed to, but I would like to understand exactly what it does on each steps of its loop.

Could you please take a look to the function below and give me a clear explanation commenting each step or the Filter and IndexOf methods?

Thank you very much in advance.

```
var arr = [6,2,6,8,9,9,9,4,5];

var unique = function(){
  return arr.filter(function(e, i, a) {
      return i === a.indexOf(e);
  })
}

unique();
```

Comment: What exactly *don't* you understand about it…?

Comment: It sounds like youre asking for a description provided by the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Also, of all the ways ive ever seen to get a unique array, I think this would be the slowest!

Comment: @Jamiec I am not using this function in a production at the moment, just would like to get clear understanding of how such a function returns unique values. But yeah, thanks for your tip, I will take a look to its performance as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indexOf` returns the [*first*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) index of an element in an array:

```
[1,2,2,3].indexOf(2); // 1
```

So if you use `filter` as in your example when it gets to the second occurance of an element the index (`i` in your example) will not be equal to the value returned by `indexOf` and be dropped. In my array above the second 2 is at position 2 which obviously doesn't strictly equal the one returned by `indexOf`.

```
[1,2,2,3].filter((value, index, array) => array.indexOf(value) === index);
// first iteration: value is 1, index is 0, indexOf is 0 0===0 keep 1
// second: value is 2, index is 1, indexOf is 1, 1===1 keep 2
// third: value is 2, index is 2, indexOf is 1, 1===2 false! toss 2
// etc.
```

The end effect is that any duplicate elements get dropped from the copy returned by `filter`. And it is a copy, the original array is not mutated.

## EDIT

I should probably mention that recent versions of JavaScript give us a better way:

```
let arrayWithDupes = [1,2,2,3];
let uniq = Array.from(new Set(arrayWithDupes)); // [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If log the values like:

```
var arr = [6,2,6,8,9,9,9,4,5];
var unique = function(){
  return arr.filter(function(e, i, a) {
      console.log('e: ' + e);
      console.log('i: ' + i);
      console.log('a: ' + a);
      return i === a.indexOf(e);
  })
}

var unq = unique();

console.log(unq);
```

you will get:

```
"e: 6"
"i: 0"
"a: 6,2,6,8,9,9,9,4,5"
```

and so on...

e = current element from array, i = index of the array, a = array source;

Filer function: "The filter() method creates an array filled with all array elements that pass a test (provided as a function)."

indexOf: "The indexOf() method searches the array for the specified item, and returns its position."

Comment: Yes, my mistake.

Comment: Also youve scraped the first line of code, so you'll get a `cannot call .filter of undefined` if you tried running this code

Comment: Lol, mad add your source array, this example is complete you request, is not obvious?!